# react-i18next: passing t function to all children or useTranslation in every child?

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I'm using `react-i18next` to translate my react app.

For every different "main" pages (navigated from the menu), I get `t()` function with `useTranslation`; and for children components of these pages, I pass the `t` with other props to the children.

I'm wondering if I was doing it the right way?

Is it better to get `t` with `useTranslation` inside each child, instead inside their parents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO using `useTranslation` in every component is the better way, because:

- your component structure is more consistent (leading to *uniformity*)
- you don't have to decide wether doing it one way or the other (which helps *conceptional integrity*, especially when working in teams)
- your components are easier to reuse (because they don't ask for things they can get on their own)
- if you are using PropTypes or TypeScript you will simply write less code, because all types are inferred automatically

Comment: Thanks! This makes thing clear. However, if I have a list component that contains many items, and the items are all same component with different props, is it still the better way to use `useTranslation` inside the item component? Would that cause any performance issue?

Comment: I don't expect it to be slower. Yet I didn't test this in regard of performance. My approach would always be to start optimising only once you encounter performance issues - not upfront.